# Create new dataframe column from the values of 2 other columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have 2 columns in my data frame. At any one instance (row), at least one of the columns has a string value in it, it is possible that the other column has NoneType in it or another string.

I want to create a 3rd column that, in the case where one of the columns is a NoneType, will take the value of the string. And in the case where both are strings, will take the concatenation of the two.

How can I do this?

```
  column1  column2         column3
0   hello     None           hello
1    None  goodbye         goodbye
2   hello  goodbye  hello, goodbye
```

Answer (score 4):

#### [Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

Use `na_rep=''` so joins with missing values do not result in `NaN` for the entire row. Then `strip` any excess separators that were joined due to missing data (assuming separator characters also don't start or end any of your words).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['hello', None, 'hello'],
                   'column2': [None, 'goodbye', 'goodbye']})

sep = ', '
df['column3'] = (df['column1'].str.cat(df['column2'], sep=sep, na_rep='')
                   .str.strip(sep))

print(df)
  column1  column2         column3
0   hello     None           hello
1    None  goodbye         goodbye
2   hello  goodbye  hello, goodbye
```

---

With many columns, where there might be streaks of missing data in the middle, the above doesn't work to remove the excess separators. Instead you could use a slow `lambda` along the rows. We join all values after dropping the nulls:

```
df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda row: ', '.join(row.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

You could replace all the `NaN`s with an empty string and then conact the columns (A and B) to create column C.

```py
df2 = df.fillna('')
df['C'] = df2.A.str.strip() + df2.B.str.strip(); #del df2;
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
       A     B    C=A+B
0      1     3       13
1      2  None        2
2    dog   dog   dogdog
3   None  None         
4  snake    20  snake20
5    cat  None      cat
```

### Dummy Data

```py
d = {
    'A': ['1', '2', 'dog', None, 'snake', 'cat'], 
    'B': ['3', None, 'dog', None, '20', None]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
       A     B
0      1     3
1      2  None
2    dog   dog
3   None  None
4  snake    20
5    cat  None
```